# Java Tetris - Set new color for each piece

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to set a new random color for each new piece (composed of 4 tiles). To draw the full piece to the board, I have a paint component in the Board class:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            if(grid[row][col] != null) {
                //if there is a non-null space, that is a Tetris piece.. fill it red
                    g.setColor(color);
                    g.fillRect(row * tilesize, col * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.drawString("(" + row + ", " + col + ")", row * tilesize, col * tilesize+10);
                }           
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see that `g.setColor()` is given a global variable `color`

As defined in the Board constructor:

`color = setColor();`

**setColor():**

```
public Color setColor() {

    Random rand = new Random();

    float r = rand.nextFloat();
    float g = rand.nextFloat();
    float b = rand.nextFloat();
    Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);

    return randomColor;
}
```

And when there is a collision, a new piece is generated, which overwrites the `color` global variable with a new random color...

```
public void collisionCheck() {
    if (newPiece.isCollision()){
        newPiece = new Piece(this, randomPiece());
        color = setColor();
    }       
}
```

This gives me this result:

All shapes are set to the same color... not what I want
[image]

Then if a new piece is generated, the color for all of them changes... again, not what I want.
[image]

I know *what* the issue is... it's that I shouldn't be overwriting the global color variable... but if I don't assign a color from the board class... but instead get the color from the tile class, as such:

`g.setColor(grid[row][col].getColor());`

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
                if(grid[row][col] != null) {
                    //if there is a non-null space, that is a Tetris piece.. fill it red
                        g.setColor(grid[row][col].getColor());
                        g.fillRect(row * tilesize, col * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        g.drawString("(" + row + ", " + col + ")", row * tilesize, col * tilesize+10);
                    }           
                }
            }
        }
```

Then each individual tile will have a new color generated each time the tiles are repainted...

[image]

My goal is to give a single piece (composed of 4 tiles) a random color... then when a new piece is generated, that first piece retains its color... and the new piece retains its color...

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: for game development, you should have a game loop instead of running everything in paintComponent()

Comment: @Jimmt I'm new to this. Can you give an example?

Comment: http://www.gameprogblog.com/generic-game-loop/#headingWhatIsGameLoop - basically, a game loop is supposed to regulate the rate at which the game runs, so that it doesn't run any faster on faster machines, or any slower on slower machines, and that the fps doesn't go too high, to maximize performance and to not max out cpu use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out how to do it... In Board class, pass `randomColor()` in as a parameter when I create newPiece:

```
public Color randomColor() {

    Random rand = new Random();

    float r = rand.nextFloat();
    float g = rand.nextFloat();
    float b = rand.nextFloat();
    Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);

    return randomColor;
}

newPiece = new Piece(this, randomPiece(), randomColor());.
```

In Piece class, loop through the tiles, `tile[i].setColor(color);`, setting the color of each tile.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
    tile[i].setColor(color);
}
```

In Tile I added `Color getColor()` which returns `setColor(color);`,

```
public Color getColor() {
    return setColor(color);
}

public Color setColor(Color myColor) {  
    color = myColor;
    return color;
}
```

Which I then use in Board class' paint component: `g.setColor(grid[row][col].getColor());`

It's definitely not the most elegant solution though. It'd be cool to learn how to do it better, and do Tetris in a "game loop", as jimmt described.

[image]

Comment: I was moments from suggesting an Object oriented approach! Glad you got it on your own though :)